# Como compartir los atributos de una clase a otra en JAVA

Tags: java, diseño-de-clases

Tengo el siguente problema,estoy realizando un ejercicio donde tengo a dos clases una llamada pacientes y otra llamada medico y por supuesto la clase main. Pero en la clase medico tengo un atributo que es paciente encargado y quiero que ahi este el nombre del paciente que esta en la clase paciente.

Esta es mi clase paciente

```
public class Paciente {
String nombre;
String apellido;
int edad;
String tipoDeSangre;
String enfermedad;
String estado;
/**
 * Constructor vacio
 */
public Paciente(){
    nombre="n/a";
    apellido="n/a";
    tipoDeSangre="n/a";
    enfermedad="n/a";
    estado="n/a";        
}
/**
 * Constructor que recibe los datos del paciente
 * @param nombre
 * @param apellido
 * @param edad
 * @param tipoDeSangre
 * @param enfermedad
 * @param estado 
 */
public Paciente(String nombre,String apellido,int edad,String tipoDeSangre,String enfermedad,String estado){
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellido=apellido;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;
    this.enfermedad=enfermedad;
    this.estado=estado;
}
/**
 * metodo que devuelve los datos
 * @return 
 */
public String devolverDatos (){
    return "Nombre: "+nombre+" \nApellido: "+apellido+" \nEdad: "+edad+" \nTipo de sangre: "+tipoDeSangre+
            " \nEnfermedad: "+enfermedad+" \nEstado: "+estado;
}
/**
 * Metodo que muestra los datos por pantalla
 */
public void mostrarDatos(){
    System.out.println(devolverDatos());
}
```

}

Ahora en mi clase medico quiero que en el atributo paciente encargado este el nombre y apellido que se guarda en la clase paciente pero no se como hacerlo.Esta es mi clase Medico.

```
public class Medico {
String nombre;
String apellido;
int edad;
String tipoDeSangre;
String pacienteEncargado;
String estado;
Paciente p1;

/**
 * Constructor vacio
 */
public Medico(){
    this.<error> = p1;
    
}
/**
 * Constructor que recibe los parametros del objeto
 * @param nombre
 * @param apellido
 * @param edad
 * @param tipoDeSangre
 * @param pacienteEncargado
 * @param estado 
 */
public Medico(String nombre,String apellido,int edad,String tipoDeSangre
,String estado){
   
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellido=apellido;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;

    this.estado=estado;
}
/**
 * metodo que devuelve datos del objeto
 * @return 
 */
public String devolverDatos(){
    return "Nombre: "+nombre+" \nApellido: "+apellido+" \nEdad: "+edad+" \nTipo de sangre: "+tipoDeSangre+
            " \nPaciente Encargado: "+pacienteEncargado+" \nEstado: "+estado;
}
/**
 * metodo que muestra los datos del objeto
 */
public void mostrarDatos(){
    System.out.println(devolverDatos());
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al leer esto:

*Ahora en mi clase medico quiero que en el atributo paciente encargado este el nombre y apellido que se guarda en la clase paciente pero no se como hacerlo.*

Intuyo que hay un problema de compresión sobre cómo funciona y cuál es el propósito de la POO.

Lo cierto es que **no necesitas un atributo paciente encargado con el nombre y el apellido**, simplemente, otorga a médico una propiedad del tipo `Paciente`, la cual contendrá todos los atributos de ese paciente: nombre, apellido, tipo de sangre, enfermedades y lo que haga falta.

Otra cosa sospechosa es que pasar una propiedad `estado` al constructor de `Medico`. ¿Qué es esa propiedad? ¿En tu diseño el `Medico` es también `Paciente` y quieres controlar el `estado` de salud del mismo? Los médicos enferman ciertamente, pero cuando eso ocurre, por lo general, son llevados por otros médicos. Cuando el `Medico` enferme, crea una instancia de `Paciente` con sus datos, hacer lo contrario es mezclar contextos y tener un spaghetti en el código.

Vamos a aplicar lo dicho en un ejemplo, observa que desde el método `devolverDatos()` de la clase `Medico`, aparte de su nombre y apellido, invocamos a su vez el método `devolverDatos()` de la propiedad `paciente` del mismo ... ¡es así como empiezas a saborear las bondades de la POO!

#### Código `>` <kbd>[`VER DEMO EN REXTESTER`](https://rextester.com/UDLI90774)</kbd>

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Paciente p1=new Paciente("P1 Nombre","P1 Apellido",50,"A+","Diabetes","Bien");
        Medico   m1=new Medico  ("M1 Nombre","M1 Apellido",45,"O+",p1);
        m1.mostrarDatos();
    }
}

     class Paciente {
        String nombre;
        String apellido;
        int edad;
        String tipoDeSangre;
        String enfermedad;
        String estado;
        /**
         * Constructor vacio
         */
        public Paciente(){    
        }
        /**
         * Constructor que recibe los datos del paciente
         * @param nombre
         * @param apellido
         * @param edad
         * @param tipoDeSangre
         * @param enfermedad
         * @param estado 
         */
        public Paciente(String nombre,String apellido,int edad,String tipoDeSangre,String enfermedad,String estado){
            this.nombre=nombre;
            this.apellido=apellido;
            this.edad=edad;
            this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;
            this.enfermedad=enfermedad;
            this.estado=estado;
        }

        /**
         * metodo que devuelve los datos
         * @return 
         */
        public String devolverDatos (){
            return String.format("Nombre: %s%nApellido: %s%nEdad: %d%nTipo de sangre: %s%nEnfermedad: %s%nEstado: %s",
                                 nombre,apellido,edad,tipoDeSangre,enfermedad,estado);
        }

        /**
         * Metodo que muestra los datos por pantalla
         * Método redundante por demás, pues puedes imprimir
         * desde devolverDatos()
         */
        public void mostrarDatos(){
            System.out.println(devolverDatos());
        }
    }

class Medico {
    String nombre;
    String apellido;
    int edad;
    String tipoDeSangre;
    Paciente paciente;

    /**
     * Constructor vacio
     */
    public Medico(){
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor que recibe los parametros del objeto
     * @param nombre
     * @param apellido
     * @param edad
     * @param tipoDeSangre
     * @param paciente 
     */
    public Medico(String nombre,String apellido,int edad,String tipoDeSangre,Paciente paciente){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
        this.edad=edad;
        this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;
        this.paciente=paciente;
    }
    /**
     * metodo que devuelve datos del objeto
     * @return 
     */
     public String devolverDatos (){
         return String.format("Nombre: %s%nApellido: %s%n%nPaciente:%n%s",
                                 nombre,apellido,paciente.devolverDatos());
     }    
    
    /**
     * metodo que muestra los datos del objeto
     */
    public void mostrarDatos(){
        System.out.println(devolverDatos());
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Nombre: M1 Nombre
Apellido: M1 Apellido

Paciente:
Nombre: P1 Nombre
Apellido: P1 Apellido
Edad: 50
Tipo de sangre: A+
Enfermedad: Diabetes
Estado: Bien
```

Pero, la POO debe ser conforme a la realidad. Y lo suyo es que un `Medico` tenga varios pacientes. Para ello, basta con crear una propiedad del tipo `List<Paciente>` en `Medico`. De nuevo, podrás gustar de las bondades de la POO.

Veamos un ejemplo:

#### Código `>` <kbd>[`VER DEMO EN REXTESTER`](https://rextester.com/RST28287)</kbd>

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Paciente> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Paciente("P1 Nombre","P1 Apellido",50,"A+","Diabetes","Bien"));
        list.add(new Paciente("P2 Nombre","P2 Apellido",30,"O+","Gripe","Mal"));
        list.add(new Paciente("P99 Nombre","P99 Apellido",80,"O-","Cáncer","Muy mal"));
        Medico   m1=new Medico  ("M1 Nombre","M1 Apellido",45,"O+",list);
        m1.mostrarDatos();
    }
}

class Paciente {
    String nombre;
    String apellido;
    int edad;
    String tipoDeSangre;
    String enfermedad;
    String estado;
    /**
     * Constructor vacio
     */
    public Paciente(){    
    }
    
    /**
      * Constructor que recibe los datos del paciente
      * @param nombre
      * @param apellido
      * @param edad
      * @param tipoDeSangre
      * @param enfermedad
      * @param estado 
     */
     public Paciente(String nombre,String apellido,int edad,String tipoDeSangre,String enfermedad,String estado){
         this.nombre=nombre;
         this.apellido=apellido;
         this.edad=edad;
         this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;
         this.enfermedad=enfermedad;
         this.estado=estado;
     }

     /**
       * metodo que devuelve los datos
       * @return 
      */
        public String devolverDatos (){
            return String.format("Nombre: %s%nApellido: %s%nEdad: %d%nTipo de sangre: %s%nEnfermedad: %s%nEstado: %s",
                                 nombre,apellido,edad,tipoDeSangre,enfermedad,estado);
        }

    /**
      * Metodo que muestra los datos por pantalla
      * Método redundante por demás, pues puedes imprimir
      * desde devolverDatos()
      */
    public void mostrarDatos(){
        System.out.println(devolverDatos());
    }
}

class Medico {
    String nombre;
    String apellido;
    int edad;
    String tipoDeSangre;
    List<Paciente> pacientes;

    /**
     * Constructor vacio
     */
    public Medico(){
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructor que recibe los parametros del objeto
     * @param nombre
     * @param apellido
     * @param edad
     * @param tipoDeSangre
     * @param paciente 
     */
    public Medico(String nombre,String apellido,int edad,String tipoDeSangre,List<Paciente> pacientes){
        this.nombre=nombre;
        this.apellido=apellido;
        this.edad=edad;
        this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;
        this.pacientes=pacientes;
    }
    /**
     * metodo que devuelve datos del objeto
     * @return 
     */
     public String devolverDatos (){
         StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
         for (Paciente p : pacientes) {
             sb.append(p.devolverDatos());
             sb.append("\n\n");
         }        
         return String.format("Nombre: %s%nApellido: %s%n%nPacientes:%n%n%s",
                                 nombre,apellido,sb.toString());
     }    
    
    /**
     * metodo que muestra los datos del objeto
     */
    public void mostrarDatos(){
        System.out.println(devolverDatos());
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
Nombre: M1 Nombre
Apellido: M1 Apellido

Pacientes:

Nombre: P1 Nombre
Apellido: P1 Apellido
Edad: 50
Tipo de sangre: A+
Enfermedad: Diabetes
Estado: Bien

Nombre: P2 Nombre
Apellido: P2 Apellido
Edad: 30
Tipo de sangre: O+
Enfermedad: Gripe
Estado: Mal

Nombre: P99 Nombre
Apellido: P99 Apellido
Edad: 80
Tipo de sangre: O-
Enfermedad: Cáncer
Estado: Muy mal
```

Answer (score 0):

En el constructor de Medico puedes recibir los datos del Paciente y concatenarlos.

```
public Medico(String nombre,String apellido,int edad,String tipoDeSangre
,String estado, String nombrePaciente, String apellidoPaciente){
   
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.apellido=apellido;
    this.edad=edad;
    this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;
    this.pacienteEncargado = nombrePaciente + " " + apellidoPaciente;
    this.estado=estado;
}
```

Otra opción es guardar los datos del paciente con un método `set` después de construido la instancia de Medico

```
public void setPacienteEncargado(String nombreConcatenado) {
   this.pacienteEncargado = nombreConcatenado;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que pasarle los datos del paciente a la instancia del médico, podría ser en el constructor o via un método setter:

a) Vía constructor:

```
/**
 * Constructor que recibe los parámetros del objeto
 * @param nombre
 * @param apellido
 * @param edad
 * @param tipoDeSangre
 * @param pacienteEncargado
 * @param estado 
 * /
public Medico(
  String nombre,
  String apellido,
  int edad,
  String tipoDeSangre,
  String estado
  Paciente paciente /* Datos del paciente */){

  this.nombre=nombre;
  this.apellido=apellido;
  this.edad=edad;
  this.tipoDeSangre=tipoDeSangre;
  this.estado=estado;

  // Nombre del paciente
  this.pacienteEncargado = paciente.nombre + " " + paciente.apellido;
}
```

b) Vía método setter:

```
public class Medico {
  ...

  public void setPacienteEncargado(Paciente paciente) {
    this.pacienteEncargado = paciente.nombre + " " + paciente.apellido;
  }

  ...
}
```

Aunque realmente la pregunta sería el paciente está asignado al médico, o es el paciente quién tiene un medico asignado; esto teniendo en cuenta que en la mayoría si no es que todos con sus mínimas excepciones de los casos, los pacientes sólo tienen un médico asignado pero los médicos a su vez tienen más de un paciente encargados al mismo tiempo. En ese caso, el paciente tendría que tener referencia a su médico de planta y el médico tendría una lista de pacientes que tiene a su cargo.